# How do I unit test this plot method?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following code which takes a document id and then iterates through output_list and creates a histogram out of the data. I want to perform a unit test on this function. I do not understand what to do it on and how to actually test that this code works because there is a histogram.

Can someone suggest to me how I can unit test this piece of code?
Can I test that country_list=[] should not be empty? or what could I test here? Could I test that a doc_id is provided? I'm not sure how to code this unit test, and am open to suggestions.

```
def onCountry(self, doc_id):
        if(doc_id==None):
            return

        output_list = self.findBySubjectDocId(doc_id)

        country_list=[]
        for x in output_list:
            country_id=x["visitor_country"]
            if(SHOW_FULL_NAMES):
                country_id=pc.country_alpha2_to_country_name(country_id)
            country_list.append(country_id)

        ts=pd.Series(country_list).value_counts().plot(kind='bar',color='purple')
        plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
        plt.xlabel('Country')
        plt.ylabel('Number of Viewers')
        plt.title("Viewers based on Country")
        ts.plot()
        plt.show()

        print("Countries of Visitors:")
        x = []
        y = []
        for k,v in Counter(country_list).items():
            x.append(k)
            y.append(v)
            print(k,"-",v)
```

Comment: What part about do you want to test? It returns nothing. It just prints stuff, do you want to check it prints the right thing? Do you want to test that it plots the right thing?

Comment: Yes. Do you know a way I could  do that? @luk2302